# How to Down Sample a video with Torch?

Tags: torch

I am struggling with downsampling a video with torch. I have a video tensor of shape `(1,frame_number,channels,h,w)`. I would like to downsample this video tensor image by image (no 3D interpolation) to have a new tensor of shape `(1,frame_number,channels,new_h,new_w)`. I want this tensor to be compatible with the backward computation.

I have tried to use resize and interpolate but it doesn't work until now. Do anyone have an idea ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the [torch docs](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/auto_examples/others/plot_video_api.html), where video frames are resized.
I created an example from this that handles batches, too. This might be what you are looking for:

```
from torchvision import transforms as t
import torch

batch_size, frame_number, channels, height, width = 1, 8, 3, 64, 64
video = torch.ones((batch_size, frame_number, channels, height, width))
video.shape #  1, 8, 3, 64, 64

transforms = [t.Resize((8, 8))]  # resize each frame to 8x8 pixels
frame_transform = t.Compose(transforms)

batch = []  # batch buffer
for batch_id in range(batch_size):
    video_frames = []  # frame buffer
    for frame in video[batch_id]:
        video_frames.append(frame_transform(frame))
    batch.append(torch.stack(video_frames, 0))
video = torch.stack(batch, 0)
video.shape  # 1, 8, 3, 8, 8
```